# Is "He told me not to argue but just agree." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, differences

> He told me not to argue but just agree.

I think the sentence above is grammatically correct, but I'm not sure.

In fact, I have a hard time choosing between the following sentences:

> He told me not to argue and just agree.
>
> He told me not to argue but to just agree.
>
> He told me not to argue and to just agree.

I seem completely lost and have been playing the guessing game. Someone help me?

Comment: They're all valid - just stylistic variants with no difference in meaning.

Comment: I would say "correct" rather than "valid". The sentences differ slightly in tone, in ways that could be influenced by the context.

Comment: It sounds clearest and least awkward (to me) when the infinitives are clarified: "He told me not to argue [one infinitive] but just to agree [other infinitive]." However, I have no idea if your original sentence is grammatically valid, so no answer from me.

Comment: @Eli Rosencruft: I struggle to imagine different contexts where any one of OP's variants would somehow be more appropriate than another. Come to that, in *this* context, I struggle to see what difference of meaning you intend between "correct" and "valid".

Comment: We usually ask "Is this grammatically correct", etc. See examples in "RELATED" sidebar. I have not seen anyone ask "Is this grammatically valid".

Comment: It might be interesting that only the first of your alternatives would have been considered correct in traditional formal grammar. In the final two ('... but to just agree' and '... and to just agree') you have split the infinitive, i.e., you have separated the word 'to' from the verb stem 'agree'. While that is not generally considered grammatically incorrect these days, one might instead say, 'He told me not to argue, just to agree' (I have also removed the problematic 'and'/'but' decision).

Comment: @JDOConal Really enjoyed your comment and found it very enlightening. It deserves an answer!

Comment: Deserves TO BE an answer, rather. :-)

Comment: @JDO: In speech we rarely find the second *to* religiously applied. Its omission is more common. OP refers to a spoken sentence.

Comment: @Kris Thanks for pointing out. That's very kind of you!

Comment: @Kris: I accept that it's more common. In my defence, I only said 'One might instead say'. I certainly would say 'He told me not to argue, just to agree', but you are right, it would be more common for someone to say 'He told me not to argue, just agree'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinitive *to* is not dispensed with in the second instance of the sentence.

It is just omitted, to be understood by the reader. This is known as ellipsis.

So the two forms of the sentence are identical, technically and semantically.

Both of them are correct.

---

[Edit] Pl. read in conjunction with my comments below re: *and* / *but*.

Comment: In response to the conjuntion (but vs and), *and* makes it sound like he is telling you not to argue *and* not to agree, while *but* makes it sound like he is telling you not to argue *but* just to agree.

Comment: @zpletan: And [but?!] what difference does it make? None at all, imho.

Comment: The ultimate implication remains the same with either *and* or *but*. However, *and* suggests to go a step further to agree, while *but* tells you to take a U-turn and agree. :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers—sorry, I thought I remembered OP's other sentences, but didn't exactly. My bad.

Comment: @Kris: In principle it's possible to draw that distinction between *and* and *but*, but [and² but²?!] in OP's context the volte-face is already implicit through the preceding *"not argue"*. Having said that, idiomatically we usually *do* opt for *"but"* in such constructions (I say this not to damn, but to offer faint praise! :)

Comment: Heh - I only made the comment because I wanted a chance to write "and and but but", but I see now that once you get started, it can become a bit of a bad habit!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and clearest is "He told me not to argue but to just agree."

The reason that this is simplest is that it is the easiest to parse without ambiguity:

```
["He told me"] -> ( (("not to") ["argue"]) / (("but to") ["just agree"]) )
```

That is, "do this not that".

The [split infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive) is not considered an error in current usage.

All of the formulations using "and" are open to the ambiguous interpretation

```
He told me not to argue [with someone about A] and [also] to just agree [with someone else about B].
```

Comment: Why not "*... not to argue --  just agree.*"?

Comment: Edited answer to address comments.

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting that only the first of your alternatives would have been considered correct in traditional formal grammar. In the final two ('... but to just agree' and '... and to just agree') you have split the infinitive, i.e., you have separated the word 'to' from the verb stem 'agree'. While that is not generally considered grammatically incorrect these days, one might instead say, 'He told me not to argue, just to agree' (I have also removed the problematic 'and'/'but' decision).

P.S. This was just a comment, but due to [popular support](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64428/is-he-told-me-not-to-argue-but-just-agree-grammatically-correct#comment122817_64428) I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to figure out, once you think about the two conjunctions individually.

The word ***and*** is defined as *a conjunction used to conjoin a word with a word, a clause with a clause, or a sentence with a sentence*.

The word ***but*** is defined as *a conjunction used for joining two ideas or statements when the second one is different from the first*.

So, the word *but* is fitting – yet that does not preclude the more generic *and* from being used.

If you want to accentuate the difference between arguing and agreeing, use *but*.  Otherwise, either one works fine.